# where in php.ini or where to change the coding of these deduced javascriptom if there is such possibility

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

where in php.ini or where to change the coding of these deduced javascriptom if there is such possibility

simply problem in that that all site is deduced in utf-8, and data received through jquery (ajax) come to cp-1251

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can enabled UTF8 in the php.ini

> > default_charset = "utf-8"

or also called the header in the PHP page with the UTF8 header:

> > header('content-type: text/html; charset: utf-8');

Comment: iconv or mb_convert_encoding on output data?